# Do applications preserve xattrs when saving?

Tags: macos, ms-office

Do applications on Mac OS X (specifically the MS Office applications, but interested in others as well) generally preserve xattrs (Extended Attributes) on documents when saving them?

For example, if I add an xattr to a file:

```
xattr -w test "test attribute" mydocument.docx
```

Then open this in MS Word, make a change, and save, is the attribute maintained? What does

```
xattr -l mydocument.docx
```

print after saving?

Comment: Why can't you test this yourself?

Comment: No mac handy atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Mac running OS X 10.9.5. When saving through a terminal editor (vim) and GUI programs (TextEdit, MS Word), xattrs are preserved.